# Device not detected with USB 2.0 extension

Tags: usb, cable, usb-2

I interfaced a USB industrial digital camera to my PC using a 1.5 M USB 2.0 cable, and the camera was detected by the PC. But because of a length issue, I added a USB extension of 5 M length to interface with the PC.

Initially, everything was fine. But after two days the PC stopped detecting the camera through the USB extension. If I remove the USB extension and connect the camera and short cable directly to the PC as originally configured, it still works fine.  The USB extension cable is fine, because when I use it to connect a pen drive, it is detected.

1. Why was the camera detected initially and not now?
2. I used a USB extension without an extra power supply. Could this be the reason? If so, then why was it detected and working for two days through same USB extension?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like all of the components are fine, it's the combination that's the problem.

1. Passive extension cables aren't supported by the USB spec.  In general, cables are designed for their length.  Long cables will have larger wires than short cables, and other design differences.  The losses and signal degradation in each cable are additive so even if the combined cable length is less than the suggested limit (5 meters for USB 2.0), the component cables may not support the combined length.
2. It is possible to create a working cable longer than the 5 meter limit, and a longer non-custom cable might work with some devices.  But it is unreliable for anything demanding.  An off-the-shelf 5 meter cable added to an off-the-shelf 1.5 meter cable isn't likely to be reliable for anything demanding.
3. The question in your case isn't really why did it work for 2 days and then stop, it's why did it work at all?  We will never know the answer to that.  Apparently, the combination was right at the edge of what would work at all, and it did manage to work for a short time (at least well enough for the camera to be detected).
4. If you can move the computer to within 5 meters of where the camera needs to be, you should be able to use an off-the-shelf cable.  Otherwise, you will need an active extension.  You can use an active extension cable (referred to as a repeater), or an inexpensive powered USB hub to connect a standard additional cable.  An active extension cable is basically a one-port USB hub built into the cable, as opposed to a passive extension cable that is just wires.

Comment: Normal USB extension and Active Extension cable are different ?

Comment: @jalath, yes.  A passive extension cable is just wires with a female connector at one end.  An active extension cable is also called a repeater.  It includes circuitry to boost the signal by resending it in both directions.  You can get the same effect by using a USB hub to add a standard cable (the active extension cable is basically a one-port USB hub built into the cable).

Comment: The camera may not work even with an active extension cable.  Some USB devices cannot tolerate the added latency of longer cables.  IOW voltage drop is not the only issue with long cables.

Comment: @sawdust, right, it's not just voltage drop; there are various signal issues as well, and latency.  But my understanding is that latency issues don't kick in for substantially greater distances than 6.5 M.  There's a limit to how many repeaters you can have.  But my understanding is that as long as you are within the maximum number of repeaters and using compliant cables that are within their length limit for each leg, latency isn't an issue (i.e., latency is a "leg" issue).  (cont'd)

Comment: I could see an interactive device having its own latency limits independent of the USB limit, but a camera is basically just a "send" device.  Are you aware of cameras having this kind of issue with a 6.5 M connection including a repeater?

Comment: @sawdust i am now to this concept,So its difficult to understand me,I just confused myself why camera detected and working for two days through same USB extension? and not now why ?

Comment: @fixer1234 I am new to this concept Can u send any data for reading so i can understand easily. I am new to this concept, I know some basics that's it

Comment: @jalath, a good starting place might be this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) explanation.  It's pretty thorough and contains additional links to more discussion.  There have also been a number of good discussions in answers here.  Use the search box with `[usb]` as a starting point.  That filters on the [usb] tag.  There are thousands of questions.  You can sort by votes to get the good ones.  You can also add additional tags or key words to refine and limit the results.  (cont'd)

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, you're lucky that the double cables ever worked at all for a camera.  There is no way to know why it worked for 2 days other than it was right at the edge of what would work, and for 2 days conditions were perfect enough so it did.  It isn't something you could replicate to get away with using this combination.

Comment: USB was designed as a solution for desktop connections, where distances would be short.  It works great at short distances, but the design has limitations that makes long distances impractical or impossible.  You can get around some of the limitations with elaborate cable designs, but it hits a hard limit with latency.  The protocol and design dictate that things must happen within a certain time.  The signal travelling through a long cable can take more than that amount of time, so USB cannot work beyond a certain distance without a repeater.